# Use HTML Form to Update SQL Data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm looking for help with my products list.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Produktliste </title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="dir" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="shop.php" method="post">
<p> <h2> Produkt hinzufügen </h2> </p>
<p> Produktname: <input type="text" name="Produktname"/> </p>
<p> Produktbeschreibung: <textarea rows=2 cols=20 name="Produktbeschreibung"></textarea> </p>
<p> Preis: <input type="text" name="Preis"/> </p>
<input type="submit" name="speichern" value="Speichern"/>
</form>

<?php
$connect = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '');
$connect->select_db('shop');
    if (@$_REQUEST["Produktname"] && @$_REQUEST["Produktbeschreibung"] && @$_REQUEST["Preis"]) {
        $produktname = @$_REQUEST["Produktname"];
        $beschreibung = @$_REQUEST["Produktbeschreibung"];
        $preis = @$_REQUEST["Preis"];
        $result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `shop`.`produkte` (`Produktname`, `Beschreibung`, `Preis`) VALUES ('$produktname', '$beschreibung', '$preis');");

        if(!$result) {
            echo "SQL Fehler: " . $connect->error;
            die;
        } else { echo "Letzte ID: " . $connect->insert_id;
        }
    }
?>

<table border="2" width="30%" style="border:1px solid #000000; border-spacing:inherit; text-align:left;">
<br><br>
<tr>
    <td> Produkt </td>
    <td> Beschreibung </td>
    <td> Preis </td>
    <td> Funktionen </td>
    <?php

        $result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM produkte");    
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $obj->Produktname . '</td><td>' . $obj->Beschreibung . '</td><td>' . $obj->Preis . ' EUR ' . '</td><td><a href="?id=' . $obj->ProduktID . '"> Bearbeiten</a>, <a href="?delete=' . $obj->ProduktID . '">Löschen </a></td></tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST["delete"])) {
            $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            $urlpart = explode('=', $url);
            $ProduktID = end($urlpart);

            $result = $connect->query("DELETE FROM `shop`.`produkte` WHERE `ProduktID` = $ProduktID;");
            header('Location: ./shop.php');
        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])) {
            $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            $urlpart = explode('=', $url);
            $ProduktID = end($urlpart);

            // Update SQL Data?
        }

        if (!$result) {
            echo "SQL Fehler: " . $connect->error;
            die;
        }
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

I'm now looking for a way to retrieve the MySQL Data with the equivalent ID into the existing HTML Form and update it back to the MySQL Database... I'm currently learning PHP at the University and I can't think any further by myself.

It needs to get done withing this PHP File, like everything else is.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: you should really use `parameterized queries`.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correct, you want to echo inserted row from database. Change the line:

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM produkte");
```

into:

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE ID_prod_column = '$insertID'");
```

Try something like this. Just change "ID_prod_column" to correct name and $insertID to correct variable.

Comment: okay, that would be step one, but how can i display the result in the HTML Input Form to edit and save the data?